# An exception while executing windows phone unit test

Tags: unit-testing, exception, windows-phone-8

I get this error when I run my unit test for Windows Phone. I use Windows Phone 8 and Visual studio 2012. I am not sure what to make out of this error:

```
An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mswptestadapter/v1': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:11.7426216) ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing code contracts for .Net and VS2012 extension:

Code Contracts for .Net - http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com%2F1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970%3FSRC%3DVSIDE&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGLZoTI_GSQJfSfJP5JuSNvv8SlOw

Code Contracts Editor Extensions VS2012 - http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com%2F02de7066-b6ca-42b3-8b3c-2562c7fa024f%3FSRC%3DVSIDE&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEHZ2ObOxX0KF5PK7DAme9C1zh6Kg